# Arithmetic Parser in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I don't really have a problem. But, it's my first time using Kotlin for any project, so I want to know if there is any problem in my code or my code can be made cleaner.

This is an arithmetic parser made in Kotlin. It can evaluate a expression like `"(6+4)/(2+3)"` to 2.0
This handles operations like

1. Power(^)
2. Divison(/)
3. Multiplication(*)
4. Subtraction(-)
5. Addition(+)

It also handles brackets.

My Kotlin Code is :-

```
import kotlin.math.pow

fun basic(rightNum:String?, leftNum:String?, op:String?):Double? {
    return when (op) {
        "+" -> {
            (rightNum?.toDouble()!! + leftNum?.toDouble()!!)
        }
        "-" -> {
            (rightNum?.toDouble()!! - leftNum?.toDouble()!!)
        }
        "*" -> {
            (rightNum?.toDouble()!! * leftNum?.toDouble()!!)
        }
        "^" -> {
            ((rightNum?.toDouble()!!).pow(leftNum?.toDouble()!!))
        }
        else -> {
            (rightNum?.toDouble()!! / leftNum?.toDouble()!!)
        }
    }
}


fun elemInside(mainString:String?, listCheck:List<String>):Boolean {
    for (ops in listCheck) {
        if (mainString?.contains(ops)!!){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

fun getOpIndex(query: String?, operations:List<String>):Array<Int> {
    var allIndex:Array<Int> = arrayOf()
    var dupQuery = query
    while (elemInside(dupQuery, operations)) {
        for (op in operations) {
            if (dupQuery?.contains(op)!!) {
                allIndex = allIndex.plusElement(dupQuery.indexOf(op))
                dupQuery = dupQuery.substring(0, dupQuery.indexOf(op)) + '1' + dupQuery.substring(dupQuery.indexOf(op) + 1)
            }
        }
    }

    allIndex.sort()
    return allIndex
}


fun parseSimple(query:String?):Double? {
    val operations = listOf("^", "/", "*", "-", "+")
    var allIndex: Array<Int> = arrayOf()

    var calcQuery = query
    while (elemInside(calcQuery, operations) && (allIndex.size > 1 || if (allIndex.isEmpty()) true else allIndex[0] != 0)) {
        for (op in operations) {
            calcQuery = calcQuery?.replace("-+", "-")
            calcQuery = calcQuery?.replace("--", "+")
            calcQuery = calcQuery?.replace("+-", "-")
            allIndex = getOpIndex(calcQuery, operations)
            if (calcQuery?.contains(op)!!) {
                val indexOp = calcQuery.indexOf(op)
                val indexIndexOp = allIndex.indexOf(indexOp)
                val rightIndex =
                    if (indexIndexOp == allIndex.lastIndex) calcQuery.lastIndex else allIndex[indexIndexOp + 1]
                val leftIndex = if (indexIndexOp == 0) 0 else allIndex[indexIndexOp - 1]
                val rightNum =
                    calcQuery.slice(if (rightIndex == calcQuery.lastIndex) indexOp + 1..rightIndex else indexOp + 1 until rightIndex)
                val leftNum = calcQuery.slice(if (leftIndex == 0) leftIndex until indexOp else leftIndex + 1  until indexOp)
                val result = basic(leftNum, rightNum, op)
                calcQuery = (if (leftIndex != 0) calcQuery.substring(
                    0,
                    leftIndex + 1
                ) else "") + result.toString() + (if(rightIndex != calcQuery.lastIndex) calcQuery.substring(
                    rightIndex..calcQuery.lastIndex
                ) else "")
            }
        }
    }
    return calcQuery?.toDouble()
}

fun getAllIndex(query: String?, char: Char, replacement:String="%"):List<Int> {
    var myQuery = query
    var indexes:List<Int> = listOf()
    while (char in myQuery!!) {
        val indexFinded = myQuery.indexOf(char)
        indexes = indexes.plus(indexFinded)
        myQuery = myQuery.substring(0 until indexFinded) + replacement + myQuery.substring(indexFinded+1..myQuery.lastIndex)
    }
    return indexes
}

fun getBrackets(query: String?): List<Int> {
    val allEndIndex = getAllIndex(query, ')')
    val allStartIndex = getAllIndex(query, '(')
    val firstIndex = allStartIndex[0]
    for (endIndex in allEndIndex) {
        val inBrac = query?.substring(firstIndex+1 until endIndex)
        val inBracStart = getAllIndex(inBrac, '(')
        val inBracEnd = getAllIndex(inBrac, ')')
        if (inBracStart.size == inBracEnd.size){
            return listOf(firstIndex, endIndex)
        }
    }
    return listOf(-1, -1)
}

fun evaluate(query:String?):Double? {
    var calcQuery = query
    var index = 0;
    // Check if brackets are present
    while (calcQuery?.contains('(')!! && index < 200){
        val startBrackets = getBrackets(calcQuery)[0]
        val endBrackets = getBrackets(calcQuery)[1]
        val inBrackets = calcQuery.slice(startBrackets+1 until endBrackets)
        if ('(' in inBrackets && ')' in inBrackets){
            val inBracValue = evaluate(inBrackets)
            calcQuery = calcQuery.substring(0, startBrackets) + inBracValue.toString() + (if(endBrackets == calcQuery.lastIndex) "" else calcQuery.substring(endBrackets+1..calcQuery.lastIndex))
        }
        else {
            val inBracValue = parseSimple(inBrackets)
            calcQuery = calcQuery.substring(0, startBrackets) + inBracValue.toString() + (if(endBrackets == calcQuery.lastIndex) "" else calcQuery.substring(endBrackets+1..calcQuery.lastIndex))
        }
        index++
    }

    return parseSimple(calcQuery)
}


fun main() {
    print("Enter the equation: ")
    val equation = readLine()
    println(evaluate(equation))
}
```

Please tell me how I can improve the code.

The github link is here: https://github.com/ProgrammerPro94/ArithematicParserKotlin

Comment: Yes, I have nearly tested for around 100 expressions using lists of strings

Comment: Do you have those tests automated? Or a list of them?

Comment: I have made a list of around 100 strings with some hard expressions and some complications and then passes each of them as a value of a parser and then compare the results of the tests of the parser and a calculator result for that expressions. They were same.

Comment: @programmerpro I think you should learn about JUnit https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/ (It can be used from Kotlin too)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using a lot of nullable types, combined with non-null assertions (`!!`). This defeats the purpose of using the nullable types in the first place. You should **as early as possible** check whether or not a value is null, and then pass it on as not-null.

For example, just looking at some of your function headers:

```
fun evaluate(query:String?):Double?

fun parseSimple(query:String?):Double?

fun basic(rightNum:String?, leftNum:String?, op:String?):Double?
```

Do these methods even make sense if any of those parameters is null? No! So don't declare them as nullable.

---

If I write `2^5` and you have variables called `leftNum` and `rightNum`, I would expect 2 to be left and 5 to be right. But your code is `rightNum.toDouble().pow(leftNum.toDouble())` and it computes correctly. That's because you're putting 2 as rightNum and 5 as leftNum for some reason.

---

You can make better use of Kotlin's amazing API, for example in this method:

```
fun elemInside(mainString:String?, listCheck:List<String>):Boolean {
    for (ops in listCheck) {
        if (mainString?.contains(ops)!!){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This could be:

```
fun elemInside(mainString:String, listCheck: List<String>): Boolean {
   return listCheck.any { mainString.contains(it) }
}
```

Which can even be written as:

```
fun elemInside(mainString:String, listCheck: List<String>): Boolean
   = listCheck.any { mainString.contains(it) }
```

---

I would strongly recommend using the [Shunting-yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to parse the expression. It would enable you to implement new features with new operators and even functions such as `sin`, `cos`, `sqrt`, and so on...

Or even negative numbers, which you don't support right now. `-2*3` breaks. It has to be written as `(0-2)*3` in order to work. Using Shunting-yard Algorithm also allows you to deal with whitespace much easier.

Order of operations is also a bit of an issue with your current approach, `2*3+4*5` returns 50.0 while I would expect it to return 6+20 = 26. Shunting-yard would help with this too.

Comment: Ok I will improve my code for negative numbers and also try to implement shunting yard algorithm.